# Is it possible to replicate data transforms into snowflake, in addition to the usual data loading?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For data replication we obvioulsy look to replicate data from raw sources and land them into something like Snowflake. There are also data transformations that must be handled on that data, and these transformations can be handled within Snowflake. Is there a way to "replicate" the actual transformations? Maybe it's a replication of SQL statements, or perhaps it's something else (some metadata representation of the transformations?).

Comment: What is the "Transformations" and what does it mean to "Replicate" them? When I think of data transformation I think of "ETL" or "ELT", wherein the transformation of data can occur before or after load into the target system. Is that you mean here?

Comment: If you implement a solution where your transformations are handled in views, then you could replicate the views.  Same with stored procedures.  Otherwise, you'd have to replicate SQL or workflows outside of Snowflake, I think.

Comment: @JNevill Good question. The data transformations I am referring to occur after the data are loaded into snowflake (ELT). Since those transformation can happen within snowflake, I was wondering if those could be replicated from elsewhere (just like the data are). But I'm not entirely sure that even makes sense (as in, why not just copy and paste the the SQL statements).

Comment: @MikeWalton thanks, yes that makes sense. If you replicated the views, would snowflake be able to know the logic to recreate those views?

Comment: It’s very unclear what you mean by replication - do you mean continuously copying data from source to target (which is the standard meaning for replication) or do you mean a one-off migration? If you do mean replication, and your source is transforming the data then why aren’t you replicating the transformed data, rather than duplicating the transformation logic in your target?

Comment: @NickW yes, one-off migration is a much better term for what I am referring to.

Comment: Ok - then how are these “transformations” implemented in the source system? As views, stored procs, etc? Are they actually part of the source system or are they built into an external ETL tool?

Comment: @NickW implemented in Informatica across various steps in their pipeline (fileshare written to DB, transformed and moved to another layer in DW, transformed some more then moved to presentation layer of DW.

Comment: In which case, no - there is no way of automatically moving all this logic from Informatica into Snowflake as they way they are  implemented is fundamentally different

Comment: @NickW thank you.